# How to get endpoint address in UserNamePasswordValidator in .NET 3.5?

Tags: wcf, .net-3.5

I need to acccess endpoint address in custom UserNamePasswordValidator in .NET 3.5.

I am settting

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
```

and

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
```

but HttpContext.Current is null in UserNamePasswordValidator.
I host service in IIS 7.5.
I tried also .NET 4.0 and it works but I need to a find solution in 3.5.

Is there any workaround?

Comment: Did you try using the OperationContext instead, the WCF way.

Comment: OperationContext is also null in UserNamePasswordValidator.

Comment: Same problem remains in 2017.